# What does this phrase mean according to the Modal Epistemic Model of logic?

Tags: modal-logic

According to the modal epistemic theory of logic, what does the statement P over P...ie p/p = p Np?

To clarify, I am asking in the context of this document, because it seems to use Np meaning not p, where p is necessary for the statement to be true:

[https://www.jstor.org/stable/20114716#:~:text=of%20knowledge%20-%20or%20epistemic%20logic%20-%20is,system%20M%2C2%20and%20in%20Knowledge%20and%20Belief%20Jaakko](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20114716#:%7E:text=of%20knowledge%20-%20or%20epistemic%20logic%20-%20is,system%20M%2C2%20and%20in%20Knowledge%20and%20Belief%20Jaakko)

Comment: In the referenced Lewis's S4 Np doesn't mean not p, it means Necessarily p, or most modern books will use □p. Perhaps a recent related [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91611/modal-logic-a-clarification) is helpful...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say when I was saying "where p is necessary for the statement to be true" not sure if that's exactly the same as what you said, but I'm just trying to understand what this would be saying logically under the definitions provided in the MET of knowledge as provided...i.e..in the link.

Comment: Lol perhaps it's just saying p/p=p therefore necessarily p? would make sense, but isn't that math and not logic? I haven't figured out what the horizontal divider symbol would be if not division.

Comment: Indeed, logic is foundation and thus a part of math, and mathematics=math+e+matics~=meta+out-of+meta, thus there's no tension here at all. Regarding your divide line I don't see in your ref, and sometimes in logic divide line may mean inference...